# How do I prevent sql alchemy from inserting the None value to field?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

The Alembic migration script :

```
def upgrade():
    uuid_gen = saexp.text("UUID GENERATE V1MC()")
    op.create_table(
        'foo',
        sa.Column('uuid', UUID, primary_key=True, server_default=uuid_gen),
        sa.Column(
            'inserted',
            sa.DateTime(timezone=True),
            server_default=sa.text("not null now()"))
        sa.Column('data', sa.Text)
    )
```

This is my Base class for SQL Alchemy:

```
Class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    inserted = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    uuid = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(TEXT)
```

It has a static mehtod for insert :

```
@staticmethod
def insert(session, jsondata):
  foo = Foo()
  foo.data = jsondata['data']
  if 'inserted' in jsondata:
      foo.inserted = jsondata['inserted']
  if 'uuid' in jsondata:
      foo.uuid = jsondata['uuid']
  session.add(foo)
  return foo
```

the purpose of the 2 if's are to simplify testing. this way i can "inject" a uuid and inserted date, to get predictible data for my tests

When trying to insert data

```
foo = Foo()
foo.insert(session, {"data": "foo bar baz"})
session.commit()
```

I get an IntegrityError :

```
[SQL: 'INSERT INTO foo (inserted, data) VALUES (%(inserted)s, %(data)s) RETURNING foo.uuid'] [parameters: {'data': 'foo bar baz', 'inserted': None}]
```

wich seem normal to me because the insert violates the "not-null" constraint in the postgres database.

How do I prevent sql alchemy from inserting the None value to the inserted field ?

While playing and testing around, I found that if the "inserted" column is defined as primary key , sql alchemy does not include the field in the insert statement.

```
def upgrade():
    uuid_gen = saexp.text("UUID GENERATE V1MC()")
    op.create_table(
        'foo',
        sa.Column('uuid', UUID, primary_key=True, server_default=uuid_gen),
        sa.Column(
            'inserted',
            primary_key=True,
            sa.DateTime(timezone=True),
            server_default=sa.text("not null now()"))
        sa.Column('data', sa.Text)
    )
```

But this is not what I want.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `server_default` in your model?

Comment: Yes the result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is the `server_default` which is missing in the `inserted` member in class `Foo`. It's only present in the alembic script. Note that the alembic definitions are *only* used when running the migrations. They do *not* affect the application. For this reason, it's a good idea to copy the exact same definitions from the alembic script to your application (or vice-versa).

Because no value is defined in the model definition, sqlalchemy seems to set this to `None` when the class is instantiated. This will then be sent to the DB which will complain. To fix this, either set `default` or `server_default` on the model definition (the class inheriting from `Base`).

Some additional notes/questions:

- Where does `UUID GENERATE V1MC()` come from? The [official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/uuid-ossp.html) look different. I replaced it with `func.uuid_generate_v1mc()`.
- The `server_default` value in your case contains `not null` which is incorrect. You should set `nullable=False` on you column attribute (see below).

#### alembic script

```
# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = THIS_IS_DIFFERENT_ON_EACH_INSTANCE!  # '1b7e145f2138'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID


def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'foo',
        sa.Column('uuid', UUID, primary_key=True,
                server_default=sa.func.uuid_generate_v1mc()),
        sa.Column(
            'inserted',
            sa.DateTime(timezone=True),
            nullable=False,
            server_default=sa.text("now()")),
        sa.Column('data', sa.Text)
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('foo')
```

#### tester.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import (
    TEXT,
    TIMESTAMP,
    UUID,
)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://michel@/michel')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                      autoflush=False,
                                      bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    inserted = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False,
                      server_default=func.now())
    uuid = Column(UUID, primary_key=True,
                  server_default=func.uuid_generate_v1mc()),
    data = Column(TEXT)

    @staticmethod
    def insert(session, jsondata):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.data = jsondata['data']
        if 'inserted' in jsondata:
            foo.inserted = jsondata['inserted']
        if 'uuid' in jsondata:
            foo.uuid = jsondata['uuid']
        session.add(foo)
        return foo


if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = Session()
    Foo.insert(session, {"data": "foo bar baz"})
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

#### output after execution

```
[9:43:54] michel@BBS-nexus  [1 background job(s)] 
/home/users/michel/tmp› psql -c "select * from foo"
                 uuid                 |           inserted            |    data     
--------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------
 71f5fd32-0602-11e6-aebb-27be4bbac26e | 2016-04-19 09:43:45.297191+02 | foo bar baz
(1 row)
```